# Analogous to SessionLocaleResolver for non-web Spring-based Java applications

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

How can I initialize Spring Application context (and all beans within) with messages corresponding to a certain locale passed to context externally at application's start up? This problem can be solved for web applications using `SessionLocaleResolver` but I can't find something like this for non-web (standard desktop) applications.

I can use certain locale for beans' initializetion if I hardcode it in XML configuration file:

```
<context:property-placeholder
file-encoding="UTF-8"
ignore-resource-not-found="true"
local-override="true"
ignore-unresolvable="true"
order="1"
system-properties-mode="FALLBACK"
location="classpath:locale/messages_ru_RU.properties" />
```

But I need to pass locale via `-D` or from some config file outside spring XML files.

Comment: Can you state exactly what you are trying to achieve? You mentioned desktop application and it is very confusing. In desktop application I see no problem, just access properties files in a standard way: `ResourceBundle rb = ResourceBundle.getBundle("messages");`. Provided that `Locale.getDefault(Category.DISPLAY)` returns ru-RU, that's the only thing you need to read Russian resources. And you can always set the default Locale with -D (although I would not recommend this).

Comment: Thank you for your concern!
One of tasks is to init values of beans' properties which are described in xml config files through ${prop.name}.
I want Spring to set values for properties depending on specified locale.